# Django View on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, parameter-passing

I'm creating a catalogue page. On this page I want to allow user to filter the products.
So I created a sidebar with checkboxes and input texts.
I would like that every time the user changes the filter parameters, the catalogue is updated.

this is my code:

html for sidebar (filter):

```
<h3>Filtri:</h3>
        <b>Marca:</b><br>
        {% for marca in marche %}
            <input type="checkbox" title="{{ marca.nome }}" value="{{ marca.nome }}" name="marca" class="marca" onclick="filtra()"> {{ marca.nome }} <br>
        {% empty %}
            <p>Nessuna Marca è ancora stata inserita.</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <b>Portata:</b> <br>
        Maggiore di
        <input type="text" title="portata" name="portata" id="portata" class="textbox-filtro" maxlength="4" onblur="filtra()"> kg
        <br><br>
        <b>Sollevamento:</b> <br>
        Maggiore di
        <input type="text" title="sollevamento" id="sollevamento" class="textbox-filtro" maxlength="4" onblur="filtra()"> mt
        <br><br>
        <b>Trazione:</b><br>
        {% for tra in trazione %}
            <input type="checkbox" title="{{ tra.trazione }}" value="{{ tra.trazione }}" id="{{ tra.trazione }}" class="trazione" onclick="filtra()"> {{ tra.trazione }} <br>
        {% empty %}
            <p>Nessuna Trazione è ancora stata inserita</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <b>Idroguida:</b><br>
        {% for idro in idroguida %}
            <input type="checkbox" title="{{ idro.idroguida }}" value="{{ idro.idroguida }}" id="{{ idro.idroguida }}" class="idroguida" onclick="filtra()"> {{ idro.idroguida }} <br>
        {% empty %}
            <p>Nessuna Idroguida è ancora stata inderita</p>
        {% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I've 5 filter groups: Marca (brand), Portata (carrying capacity),  Sollevamento (lift), Trazione (traction) and Idroguida (power steering).

Every time you edit these values, the javascript function filtra() is called... so onblur for text input and onclick for checkboxes.

Here the javascript code:

```
<script>
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }



        function filtra() {
            var marche_selezionate = [];
            var marca_check = document.getElementsByClassName('marca');
            for(var i = 0; i < marca_check.length; i++){
                if(marca_check[i].checked){
                    marche_selezionate.push(marca_check[i].value);
                }
            }
            marche_selezionate = marche_selezionate.join(',');

            var portata_selezionata = document.getElementById('portata').value;
            var sollevamento_selezionata = document.getElementById('sollevamento').value;

            var trazioni_selezionate = [];
            var trazione_check = document.getElementsByClassName('trazione');
            for(i = 0; i < trazione_check.length; i++){
                if(trazione_check[i].checked){
                    trazioni_selezionate.push(trazione_check[i].value);
                }
            }

            var idroguida_selezionate = [];
            var idroguida_check = document.getElementsByClassName('idroguida');
            for(i = 0; i < idroguida_check.length; i++){
                if(idroguida_check[i].checked){
                    idroguida_selezionate.push(idroguida_check[i].value);
                }
            }


            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });

            var postUrl = "{% url 'carrellielevatori:carrellielevatori' %}";
            $.ajax({
                url: postUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'marche_selezionate': marche_selezionate},
                success: function(result){
                    alert('success');
                    },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                  }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

so, after setting up csrf token, in way to avoid the error "403 forbidden", I start looking and all the parameters and set up the 5 variables that I would like to pass at the view in way to filter up the catalogue.

I've also added some alert in the ajax call in way to know if it's successful or not. It is. The alert with "success" appear.

The problem is that everything stops here.
In fact, it seems nothing happens in the view.

here the code of the view:

```
def carrellielevatori(request):
  lista_carrelli = Carrelli.objects.all()
  lista_marche = Marche.objects.all()
  lista_trazione = Trazione.objects.all()
  lista_idroguida = Idroguida.objects.all()

  footerForm = MailForm()

  method = 'get'
  if request.is_ajax():
    method = 'ajax'
    return render(request,
              'carrellielevatori/carrellielevatori.html',
              {
                  'title': 'Carrelli Elevatori - Giemme Lift s.r.l.',
                  'footerForm': footerForm,
                  'year': datetime.now().year,
                  'carrelli': lista_carrelli,
                  'marche': lista_marche,
                  'trazione': lista_trazione,
                  'idroguida': lista_idroguida,
                  'method':method,
              })
```

to understand if it works, I've set up the variable method to "get" and displayed it on the page. Then in the ajax "if", I change the value to "ajax".
So it should change, right? the text remains "get" and never changes to "ajax".

This is a first try to see if it works. Once I know this work I'll proceed to filter the query that with the products. But if this does not work it's useless.

PS. Yes in the ajax call I pass just one parameters. This is to know if it works. Later I will proceed adding the other parameters in the data field.

To conclude, can you please tell me why does not enter in the in if request.is_ajax()':
Is this in not the right way, how can I filter the oringal query?
I've also tried with if request.method == 'POST', but i get the same result.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your python view (an extra quote after `request.is_ajax()`).  Is that intentional or a copy & paste error?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how I would do it:

```
@csrf_exempt
def carrellielevatori(request):
  lista_carrelli = Carrelli.objects.all()
  lista_marche = Marche.objects.all()
  lista_trazione = Trazione.objects.all()
  lista_idroguida = Idroguida.objects.all()    
  footerForm = MailForm()    
  method = 'get'
  if request.is_ajax():
      method = 'ajax'
      return JsonResponse({
          'title': 'Carrelli Elevatori - Giemme Lift s.r.l.',
          'footerForm': footerForm,
          'year': datetime.now().year,
          'carrelli': lista_carrelli,
          'marche': lista_marche,
          'trazione': lista_trazione,
          'idroguida': lista_idroguida,
          'method':method,
      })
```

In the JS:

```
  function filtra() {
        var marche_selezionate = [];
        var marca_check = document.getElementsByClassName('marca');
        for(var i = 0; i < marca_check.length; i++){
            if(marca_check[i].checked){
                marche_selezionate.push(marca_check[i].value);
            }
        }
        marche_selezionate = marche_selezionate.join(',');

        var portata_selezionata = document.getElementById('portata').value;
        var sollevamento_selezionata = document.getElementById('sollevamento').value;

        var trazioni_selezionate = [];
        var trazione_check = document.getElementsByClassName('trazione');
        for(i = 0; i < trazione_check.length; i++){
            if(trazione_check[i].checked){
                trazioni_selezionate.push(trazione_check[i].value);
            }
        }

        var idroguida_selezionate = [];
        var idroguida_check = document.getElementsByClassName('idroguida');
        for(i = 0; i < idroguida_check.length; i++){
            if(idroguida_check[i].checked){
                idroguida_selezionate.push(idroguida_check[i].value);
            }
        }

        var postUrl = "{% url 'carrellielevatori:carrellielevatori' %}";
        $.post(postUrl, {'marche_selezionate': marche_selezionate},
            function(result){
                alert('success');
            }).fail(function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            });
    }
```